# Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Commands.ClusterHealth

Tags: c#, caching, appfabric

I am using AppFabric 1.1 on my Windows8 machine. It is running good. I want to record the cache health in background(Windows Service C#). But the output of command 'Get-CacheClusterHealth' return an array of type {Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Commands.ClusterHealth}.

I am unable to find this data type or the required reference dll anywhere. Please help me out.
I have tried using object data type, but runtime casting throws an Invalid casting exception.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there isn't any, [according to this MSDN forums thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/31426a09-a365-4710-9a4d-01ae14da74de/more-information-on-output-type-for-getcacheclusterhealth?forum=velocity): however, the thread contains some useful information:

> The assembly where all the powershell commands for AppFabric live is
>   in
>   %windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\DistributedCacheAdministration
>   (Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.ManagementPS.dll)

Also:

> Console output that you see for for any Powershell cmdelt is
>   constructed by the cmdlet through a format file.
>
> For DistributedCacheAdmin cmdlets, the format file is
>   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Caching.ManagementPS.format.ps1xml.
>   This file contains the script on how the ClusterHealth object is used
>   to display the output you see, this will help you understand the
>   object without going through reflector.

Though the thread is from 2011, Microsoft have been too busy to action this promise:

> In future, we will addd documentation for the powershell
>   command-let's.